# Spring boot many to many relation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a table say it a course where the column has a categoryid with a sample of for example "15|16"
and i also have a table category that consist of categoryid and its name. is it possible to like split the string into an array first, and after that i find the name of its category based on each categoryid from the course table? by doing that i dont have to use manytomany relation which require JoinTable in spring boot.

i tried to split the string but i cant find any method to match each categoryid to category table

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.